# Chef HA DRBD Solution in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, high-availability

we would like to build chef HA setup(2 backend, 2 frontend) using DRBD solution in AWS.

we are using Secondary IP as backend virtual IP for setup. Entire setup is working fine when primary backend is up, when we turn off primary and secondary becomes primary, front end services are not working as it is not able to reach on virtual ip.

How can we define virtual ip in aws. why is it failing to redirect requests to another server when primary is down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AWS Elastic IP (or ENI) to implement this, which means a substantially more complex failover script than the built-in stuff in heartbeat et al. Generally not worth it compared to using a load balancer instead.

Comment: We tried using HAProxy for VIP for backend servers, but front end servers are not able to listen properly.

Comment: You can't listen on IPs except those issued to you by Amazon. The hypervisor wouldn't know where to send packets.